# getting unsupported media type in spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have written a controller. I just modified it for accepting a list of object rather than only a object. so I created a wrapper class with list of original objects. But after this i am getting 415 - unsupported media type. which i am not been able to figure out why its happening. Tried almost all suggestions i could find.

Controller class :

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> addCPCodeUser(HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestBody CPCodeUserWrapper users) {
```

Wrapper class :

```
public class CPCodeUserWrapper {

   private List<CPCodeUser> users;

   .... setters and getters ...

}
```

original class :

```
public class CPCodeUser {

   private String userId;
   private String name;
   List<String> roles;
   .... setters and getters....
}


url - v1/users/
JSON : 
    {
"users" : [{
                    "userId" : "user1",
                    "roles" : ["role1", "role2"]
        },{
                    "userId" : "user2",
                    "roles" : ["role1", "role2"]
        }]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your POJOs have no argument constructors? I've had very obscure errors when the JSON library hasn't been able to instantiate the objects and the exceptions get obfuscated by spring.

Are you using the MockMVC framework to test your controllers? I find unit tests often give much clearer exceptions that when the app is deployed

Answer (score 0):

Can you try modifying your `CPCodeUser` as follows:

```
 public class CPCodeUser {

   private String userId;
   private List<String> roles;
   .... setters and getters....
}
```